# Duplication of registration in Java

Tags: java

This is my first java program i wrote for my assignment, i faced problem where there is duplication of account registration. My idea is the addStudent method checks if the input ID already exist in the textfile, then write the new account into the textfile. But it turns out it still write the new student account into the textfile even the ID already exist.

Here is the code when register button is clicked.

```
try {
    Student st = new Student();
    st.setCategory("Student");
    st.setStudID(studentID.getText());
    st.setName(name.getText());
    st.setEmail(email.getText());
    st.setPhone(phone.getText());
    st.setDegreeLevel(Integer.parseInt(level.getText()));

    String outcome = new StudentAccessor().addStudent(st);

    if (outcome.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Student Added Successfully");
    } else if (outcome.equalsIgnoreCase("undone")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Failed to register, Student already exists.");
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
}
```

Here is the methods that it calls:

```
public String addStudent(Student student) throws IOException {
    String feedback = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < allStudents.size(); i++) {
        Student a = allStudents.get(i);

        if (student.getStudID().equals(a.getStudID())) {
            feedback = "undone";
        } else{
            String entry = student.getStudID() + "," + student.getName() +
                    "," + student.getEmail() + "," + student.getDegreeLevel() +
                    "," + student.getPhone() + "," +
                    student.getCategory();

            pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Student.txt",true));
            pw.println(entry);
            pw.close();

            feedback = "done";
        }
    }

    return feedback;
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a sensible constructor to the `Student` class. I would say that a student, for instance, is required to have a name.

Comment: You might want to override `equals()` in the Student class. that way, you can ask if a given student is contained in a `List` of students by it's id

Comment: @Chun Yong, have you got your problem solved?

Comment: The problems are solved guys, thank you for all the helps !

Comment: @Mukit09 ur solution solved my problem.

Comment: You can upvote and accept the answer then. :) And obviously, you are most welcome. @ChunYong

Answer (score 1):

Your method should be like this:

```
public String addStudent(Student student) throws IOException {
    String feedback = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < allStudents.size(); i++) {
        Student a = allStudents.get(i);

        if (student.getStudID().equals(a.getStudID())) {
            feedback = "undone";
            break;
        }
    }

    if(feedback == null) {
        String entry = student.getStudID() + "," + student.getName() +
                "," + student.getEmail() + "," + student.getDegreeLevel() +
                "," + student.getPhone() + "," +
                student.getCategory();

        pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Student.txt",true));
        pw.println(entry);
        pw.close();
        feedback = "done";
    }

    return feedback;
}
```

You need to compare all the students. Then only you can tell if the id exists or not. What you are doing now, once id is not matched with any student, you are adding that student.

Suppose, a student has the same id with the one you sent to the method. But it is in the second index of the list. Now your tried one will compare the id with the first student and will not found equal. Then it will add the student in the data structure.

Hope, you got it. :)

Comment: can add the stop condition to the for loop

Comment: Don't get you. @SharonBenAsher

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < allStudents.size() && student.getStudID().equals(allStudents.get(i).getStudID()) ; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor your code a bit: Adding a student should only happen if the ID is not in the list of the already known student IDs.
So you could iterate over all the existing students first. If the ID of the student to add is found, you can immediately return "undone".

If your iteration over all students is finished (without returing) you can assume that the ID is not in the list of known students and

- add the student
- return "done"

With the current code you are iterating over the list of existing students.

- If the ID of the current student is same with the one to add, you set the feedback to undone
- If the IDs are different you add the new student and set feedback to "done" --> For each student in the list with a different ID to the one to add, an entry is created.

Answer (score -1):

```
public String addStudent(Student student) throws IOException {
    if (allStudents.contains(student.getStudID())) {
        return "undone";
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(student.getStudID()).append(",")
            .append(student.getName()).append(",")
            .append(student.getEmail()).append(",")
            .append(student.getDegreeLevel()).append(",")
            .append(student.getPhone()).append(",")
            .append(student.getCategory());

    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Student.txt", true))) {
        pw.println(sb.toString());
    }

    return "done";
}
```

Comment: 1) the posted code is incorrect. `allStudents` list contains `Student` instances that cannot be compared with a student id.    
2) code dump without any explanation will not help OP understand how to fix his/her code

Comment: `allStudents` is `java.util.ArrayList` type of `java.util.String` right? `getStudID()` returns `java.String` right? So what's the problem here?? Check for method `public boolean contains(Object o)`.

Comment: @Stefan Freitag you are wrong - you can compare student id by using method `student.getStudID()`.

Comment: according to this line from the question `Student a = allStudents.get(i);` one can deduce that the list is of `Student` generic type.